# Localise float notation

Tags: python, localization

In Python a float has the following notation: `35.45`. However in Belgium the notation is a bit different: `34,78` . For my thesis it's very important that the floats are printed in the right notation. I could convert every float to a string and change the `'.'` to a `','` but I wondered if there was any other solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.str) function from [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) package:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "nl_BE")
'nl_BE'
>>> locale.str(234.2)
'234,2'
```

You can also convert localised string to float:

```
>>> locale.atof("23424,2")
23424.2
```

Comment: This is a good solution when the program is rather small. I'm making a graphical user interface where a lot of float values must be printed. I wondered if their was a way to change this once in stead of using this transformation the multiple times. The program runs in a linux environment.

Comment: And when I tried to use this. I always get the error: locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: @Driedan you should use `nl_NL.UTF-8` or `nl_NL` on linux. You can use `locale.format_string` method which is the same as `format %  val`. There is no good way to change behaviour of standard functions